# Bash - Check If given argument exits

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a separate shell script that runs my docker-compose environment in attached mode or detached if I pass `-d` or `--detach` argument. It works fine when I pass this argument (`./run-env.sh -d`) but it doesn't when I run my script without any option ( `./run-env`, just getting blank output and docker-compose doesn't run), where can be a problem?

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for arg in "$@"; do
    if [ "$arg" = '-d'  ] || [ "$arg" = '--detach'  ]
    then
         docker-compose  -f docker-compose.local-environment.yml up --build -V --detach
    else
         docker-compose  -f docker-compose.local-environment.yml up --build -V --abort-on-container-exit
    fi
done
```

Comment: If you run the script with no argument, then `for arg in "$@"` iterates zero times.

Comment: Thanks, for navigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you don't give argument, you don't even enter the `for` loop, that's why nothing happens.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# By default, use '--abort-on-container-exit' option
abort_or_detach="--abort-on-container-exit"

# Search for a parameter asking to run in detached mode
for arg in "$@"; do
    if [ "$arg" = '-d'  ] || [ "$arg" = '--detach'  ]
    then
         abort_or_detach="--detach"
    fi
done

# Run with the correct option
docker-compose -f docker-compose.local-environment.yml up --build -V $abort_or_detach
```

Here in this script, you call one time `docker-compose`, and you can manage easily the options with the `for` loop

Also, with your first try, you would launch `docker-compose` as many times as you have different parameters. Here, you treat them, and then do a single launch

Answer (score 2):

`for arg in "$@"` iterates over the arguments.  When you pass no arguments, it iterates zero times.  Instead, try something like:

```
extra=--abort-on-container-exit
for arg; do
    case "$arg" in
    -d|--detach) extra=--detach
    esac
done

docker-compose  -f docker-compose.local-environment.yml up --build -V $extra
```

Note that this is one of those cases where you do *not* want to put quotes around `$extra`, because if `extra` is the empty string you don't want to pass anything to docker-compose.  (Here, the default will ensure it is not empty, but this is a fairly common pattern and there are cases where it will be the empty string.)

Comment: To avoid unquoted expansions, you could also keep the parameters in an array. An empty array expands, even when quoted, to nothing. Or you could use `${extra:+"$extra"}`.